# Resource bundles under wildfly

Tags: jsp, jboss, resources, wildfly

i have a wildfly 15 app server
and my application is a war file was deploy to wildfly

i need to edit Resource bundles file and change some word 
how i can do this after deploy like tomcat

Answer (score 0):

You would need to open the WAR file, find the resource folder, which contains the resource bundle file, and edit that. Using something like 7-zip lets you do this without much hassle - configure an editor in 7-zip, edit the file from within 7-zip (typically by hitting F4), and when you close the editor, the file inside the WAR will be updated.

If your web app is not overly complex, Wildfly should even be able to re-deploy it without restarting the appserver.